# Using the MoreLikeThisHandler with SolrNet

Tags: solr, solrnet

I am using Solr/SolrNet and would like to use the MoreLikeThisHandler to provide my users with facets based on the similar results. Is this possible with SolrNet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SolrNet does not currently support MoreLikeThisHandler directly. You may use [the MoreLikeThisHandler *component*](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MoreLikeThis).

See http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/issues/detail?id=143

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, perhaps I could offer a patch for this particular feature?